# Mezzanine - Django Page - RichText

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have a class like below

```
class sitepage(Page, RichText):
    featuredimage = FileField(_('File'), blank=True, max_length=200,
                          upload_to='featured', format='Image')
    featuredimagetitle = models.CharField(_('Featured Image Title'), blank=True,
                                      max_length=200)
    featuredimagebgchoices = (
        ('R', 'Red'),
        ('B', 'Blue'),
        ('G', 'Green'),
        ('O', 'Orange'),
    )
    featuredimagebg = models.CharField(_('Featured Image Background'),
                                   max_length=1, default='R',
                                   choices=featuredimagebgchoices)
    featuredimagebrief = models.TextField(_('Description - Featured Image'),
                                      blank=True, max_length=1000)
```

However I am unable to render content with it on template file sitepage.html with this

```
{{ page.sitepage.content|richtext_filters|safe }}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple mistake in your template. The part `page.sitepage.content` is a path that probably doesn't exist since there is no way to have a second app with the name "page" (see [issue #1443](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1443)). It should instead be `myapp.sitepage.content`.

Comment: My app's name is `sitetheme` and `sitetheme.sitepage.content` doesn't work.